# Detect Recent Anomalies

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, time-series, clustering, data

I'm trying to see how to approach this problem: I have a dataset of fraud transactions. There are several categorical columns, like country, type, merchant, etc. All of the records are considered fraud. I'd like to see how to detect recent patterns (for example, if there are recent (say last 3 days) of a spike in fraud for X country and Y merchant, or other combinations.
Since the fraud data follows certain seasonality (for example, weekdays are more common), how could I reduce that to detect true deviations and identify the particular categories involved?

Thank you!